# skip certain modules during deploy in multi-module maven java project on appengine w/ appengine-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, appengine-maven-plugin

I have a multi-module maven java project.  In the parent pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>batch-worker</module>
    <module>be</module>
    <module>scheduler</module>
    <module>migrations</module>
</modules>
```

Both the `migrations` and `core` modules aren't services I wish to deploy but just common packages used throughout all services.

When i attempt a deploy with `mvn appengine:deploy`, I receive goal execution failures because the `core` and `migrations` modules do not define an `app.yaml` as they are not deployable services.

How do I skip these and omit them from the deploy?

Comment: Hi, can you inform of the java environment you want to use?
As it is a project architecture question, could you also include a tree of the files?

Comment: [Modules denote services to be deployed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#module). Have you tried removing the  core and migrations from modules?

Comment: @Juancki app engine modules and maven modules are separate concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your services in the [maven plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <services>
        <!-- Default service-->
        <service>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}-${project.version}</service>
        <!-- other service-->
        <service>${project.parent.basedir}/other_module/target/other_module_finalName-${project.version}</service>
      </services>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, in the documentation the services are take into account only for start/stop command and not for deploy. I don't know if it works.

Let me know.